# Odd Fortran Pointer Syntax

Tags: syntax, fortran, fortran77

In some Fortran 77 code I have to deal with, there are pointers declared in a very odd way,

```
 pointer  (iuu     , uu      ), (ivv     , vv      ),
 $        (it      , t       ), (iq      , q       ), (ips     , ps      ),
 $        (ittm    , ttm     ), (itqm    , tqm     ), (ipsm    , psm     ),
```

What do the parenthesis here mean?  Anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are [Cray pointers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Cray-pointers.html), a non-standard type of pointer that uses regular `integer` variables to store the memory address of the target, which may be another variable or a procedure. They were introduced because programmers wanted this functionality and Fortran 77 had no native pointer facility.

The parentheses in your code are assignment statements for Cray pointers: `pointer (iptr, target) [, ...]`.

If at all possible, you should consider changing these to standard Fortran pointers, since their usage is subject to fewer restrictions and assumptions, and they are obviously supported by all compilers that implement Fortran 90.

Comment: thanks!  Googling for odd syntax (mysterious parenthesis) wasn't helping

Comment: Unfortunately, it's part of 40 year old government written code that I have to build and use with almost no support, and use without ever updating it. :(

Comment: @Matt: I was afraid of that... I guess this is a downside of having a language with such a long heritage. Oh well, if it ain't broke...! At least gfortran is a free compiler that luckily supports many of these non-standard/legacy features.

Comment: As a side note, if cray pointers are the only way to get procedure pointers until a much newer fortran standard (2003?  2008? -- Not sure which...)

Comment: The DEC/Compaq/HP Fortran extensions also supported that style of pointer (see http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/Fortran/docs/lrm/lrm0640.htm#df_pointer_stmt).  BTW, the latest Intel Fortran compiler versions still understand this pointer style.  It's a sleeping dog; let it alone.